# Как можно расположить блоки в одну строку?

Tags: html, css, css3, html5

Подскажите, как сделать так, чтобы дочерние div расположились в ряд и **выходили за пределы** родительского элемента?
Когда ставлю `display: flex`, то блоки сжимаются в родительском элементе и не выходят за него. 
Вот пример:

```css
.wrap {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: lightblue;
  padding: 10px;
}
.block {
  width: 150px;
  height: inherit;
  background-color: orange;
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Flex на [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/flex)**

```css
.wrap {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: lightblue;
  padding: 10px;
  
  display: flex;
}

.block {
  width: 150px;
  height: inherit;
  background-color: orange;
  border: 1px solid;
  
  flex-shrink: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
</div>
```